# SyntaxError: Unexpected string in msw

Tags: reactjs, mocking, service-worker, msw, mswjs

Recently i started getting this error for mock service worker (msw) in my react project.

Details:

- Node v16.19.1
- vite/3.2.6 linux-x64 node-v16.19.1
- react 18.2.0

Checked google, github issues but no good.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the `graphql` package releasing a build that cannot run in the browser. Since MSW depends on `graphql`, the error surfaces for you when you try to run MSW in the browser.

The issue has been resolved in the `graphql` package, although I've heard that it has regressed since then and you have to pin the `graphql` version in order for it to remain fixed. [`graphql@16.7.1`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/releases/tag/v16.7.1) seems to be fixing this issue.

You can use `overrides`  with NPM (and `resolutions` with Yarn) to pin that module's version in place:

```json
// package.json
{
  "overrides": {
    "graphql": "16.7.1"
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this won't regress on the latest GraphQL package and you will be able to use MSW without errors.

Comment: Thanks. Atleast i know the reason now. Tried your suggestion but its still getting the same error.

Comment: Try even later version of GraphQL: 16.8.1.

Comment: In my case this solution helps but only with version: `"graphql": "16.6.0"`.